# How do we remake program to open xml file and read percent value after price word and change this value from

Tags: java, c#, c++, powershell

How do we remake program to open xml file in windows form and read percent value after price word in file MIK_RT.xml and can be change this percent value from windows in windows form and save file with new value by clicking ok button?

can you remake my program in windows form or insert this powershell code in windows forms?  file need to be save in utf8 encoding

```
$outputFile = 'MIK_RT.xml'
write-output $outputFile
[xml](Get-Content "$outputFile") | ForEach-Object {$_.SelectNodes('//FieldCostOptions/IncreaseCost') |ForEach-Object {$_.GetAttribute("Percent")}; write-output $node.percent }
$inputpercent = Read-Host -Prompt 'percent'

[xml](Get-Content "$outputFile") | ForEach-Object {$_.SelectNodes('//FieldCostOptions/IncreaseCost') | ForEach-Object {$_.SetAttribute("Percent", $inputpercent)};  $_.Save('Output.xml')}
```

file for editing MIK_RT.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PriceConfiguration Name="MIK_RT" Version="1">
    <Description></Description>
    <AuthorID>s0011373519</AuthorID>
    <LastEditedBy>s0011373519</LastEditedBy>
    <LastUpdate>14.11.2019 12:56:27</LastUpdate>
    <File Type="XLS" Engine="0">
        <FilesMask>E:\FTP\PRICE_FORCEAUTO_MIK\RT.xls</FilesMask>
        <IncludeFiles></IncludeFiles>
        <ExcludeFiles></ExcludeFiles>
        <Macro OnStart="" />
        <XLSoptions>
            <Password></Password>
            <MergeXLSsheets>1</MergeXLSsheets>
        </XLSoptions>
        <CSVoptions>
            <RowsSeparator>13-10</RowsSeparator>
            <ColumnsSeparator>59</ColumnsSeparator>
            <AddHeaderRow>0</AddHeaderRow>
            <UseBrackets>0</UseBrackets>
            <Encoding>windows-1251</Encoding>
        </CSVoptions>
        <ReplaceTable Name="Price Codes" IsEmpty="False">
            <Replacement Find="{@КодПрайса}" ReplaceWith="" />
            <Replacement Find="{@ИмяФайлаДляПрайса}" ReplaceWith="" />
        </ReplaceTable>
    </File>
    <Sheets>
        <SheetConfiguration index="1">
            <Name>Обработчик листа</Name>
            <Description></Description>
            <SheetSelectMode>1</SheetSelectMode>
            <SheetName>Итого_Наценка_Остатков</SheetName>
            <SheetIndex>1</SheetIndex>
            <ReplaceTable Name="Price Sheet Codes" IsEmpty="False">
                <Replacement Find="{@КодЛиста}" ReplaceWith="" />
                <Replacement Find="{@ИмяФайлаДляЛиста}" ReplaceWith="" />
            </ReplaceTable>
            <PriceFields>
                <Field index="1" Enable="1">
                    <Name>Артикул</Name>
                    <SheetColumn>2</SheetColumn>
                    <UseCellText>1</UseCellText>
                    <Required>1</Required>
                    <ValueMode>0</ValueMode>
                    <KeepValue>0</KeepValue>
                    <KeepLevel>0</KeepLevel>
                    <FieldFunctions Enabled="0" Version="1" />
                    <FieldConditions Enable="0" Version="1" />
                    <ReplaceTableName>Артикул (EXIST_RT)</ReplaceTableName>
                </Field>
                <Field index="2" Enable="1">
                    <Name>Наименование</Name>
                    <SheetColumn>3</SheetColumn>
                    <ValueMode>0</ValueMode>
                    <KeepValue>0</KeepValue>
                    <KeepLevel>0</KeepLevel>
                    <FieldFunctions Enabled="0" Version="1" />
                    <FieldConditions Enable="0" Version="1" />
                    <ReplaceTableName>Наименование (FA)</ReplaceTableName>
                </Field>
                <Field index="3" Enable="1">
                    <Name>Производитель</Name>
                    <SheetColumn>1</SheetColumn>
                    <Required>1</Required>
                    <ValueMode>0</ValueMode>
                    <KeepValue>0</KeepValue>
                    <KeepLevel>0</KeepLevel>
                    <FieldFunctions Enabled="0" Version="1" />
                    <FieldConditions Enable="0" Version="1" />
                    <ReplaceTableName>Производитель (FA_RT)</ReplaceTableName>
                </Field>
                <Field index="4" Enable="1">
                    <Name>Наличие</Name>
                    <SheetColumn>4</SheetColumn>
                    <Required>1</Required>
                    <ValueMode>0</ValueMode>
                    <KeepValue>0</KeepValue>
                    <KeepLevel>0</KeepLevel>
                    <FieldFunctions Enabled="1" Version="1">
                        <Function CodeName="Replace" Enabled="1" param1="&gt;" param2="" />
                    </FieldFunctions>
                    <FieldConditions Enable="0" Version="1" />
                </Field>
                <Field index="5" Enable="1">
                    <Name>Цена</Name>
                    <SheetColumn>5</SheetColumn>
                    <Required>1</Required>
                    <ValueMode>0</ValueMode>
                    <KeepValue>0</KeepValue>
                    <KeepLevel>0</KeepLevel>
                    <FieldFunctions Enabled="1" Version="1">
                        <Function CodeName="CompareNumbers" Enabled="1" param1="2499" param2="1000000" />
                    </FieldFunctions>
                    <FieldConditions Enable="0" Version="1" />
                    <FieldCostOptions Enabled="1" Version="1">
                        <IncreaseCost Enabled="1" Percent="-5" />
                    </FieldCostOptions>
                </Field>
                <Field index="6" Enable="1">
                    <Name>ЦенаЗакупа</Name>
                    <SheetColumn>5</SheetColumn>
                    <ValueMode>0</ValueMode>
                    <KeepValue>0</KeepValue>
                    <KeepLevel>0</KeepLevel>
                    <FieldFunctions Enabled="0" Version="1" />
                    <FieldConditions Enable="0" Version="1" />
                </Field>
                <Field index="7" Enable="1">
                    <Name>ПР</Name>
                    <SheetColumn>1</SheetColumn>
                    <ValueMode>1</ValueMode>
                    <Formula>RT</Formula>
                    <KeepValue>0</KeepValue>
                    <KeepLevel>0</KeepLevel>
                    <FieldFunctions Enabled="0" Version="1" />
                    <FieldConditions Enable="0" Version="1" />
                </Field>
                <Field index="8">
                    <Name>Срок_ZZAP</Name>
                    <SheetColumn>1</SheetColumn>
                    <ValueMode>0</ValueMode>
                    <KeepValue>0</KeepValue>
                    <KeepLevel>0</KeepLevel>
                    <FieldFunctions Enabled="0" Version="1" />
                    <FieldConditions Enable="0" Version="1" />
                </Field>
                <Field index="9">
                    <Name>КодСтраны</Name>
                    <SheetColumn>1</SheetColumn>
                    <ValueMode>0</ValueMode>
                    <KeepValue>0</KeepValue>
                    <KeepLevel>0</KeepLevel>
                    <FieldFunctions Enabled="0" Version="1" />
                    <FieldConditions Enable="0" Version="1" />
                </Field>
                <Field index="10">
                    <Name>Страна</Name>
                    <SheetColumn>1</SheetColumn>
                    <ValueMode>0</ValueMode>
                    <KeepValue>0</KeepValue>
                    <KeepLevel>0</KeepLevel>
                    <FieldFunctions Enabled="0" Version="1" />
                    <FieldConditions Enable="0" Version="1" />
                </Field>
                <Field index="11">
                    <Name>ГТД</Name>
                    <SheetColumn>1</SheetColumn>
                    <ValueMode>0</ValueMode>
                    <KeepValue>0</KeepValue>
                    <KeepLevel>0</KeepLevel>
                    <FieldFunctions Enabled="0" Version="1" />
                    <FieldConditions Enable="0" Version="1" />
                </Field>
                <Field index="12">
                    <Name>ИНН_Поставщика</Name>
                    <SheetColumn>1</SheetColumn>
                    <ValueMode>0</ValueMode>
                    <KeepValue>0</KeepValue>
                    <KeepLevel>0</KeepLevel>
                    <FieldFunctions Enabled="0" Version="1" />
                    <FieldConditions Enable="0" Version="1" />
                </Field>
                <Field index="13">
                    <Name>КПП_Поставщика</Name>
                    <SheetColumn>1</SheetColumn>
                    <ValueMode>0</ValueMode>
                    <KeepValue>0</KeepValue>
                    <KeepLevel>0</KeepLevel>
                    <FieldFunctions Enabled="0" Version="1" />
                    <FieldConditions Enable="0" Version="1" />
                </Field>
                <Field index="14">
                    <Name>НомерН</Name>
                    <SheetColumn>1</SheetColumn>
                    <ValueMode>0</ValueMode>
                    <KeepValue>0</KeepValue>
                    <KeepLevel>0</KeepLevel>
                    <FieldFunctions Enabled="0" Version="1" />
                    <FieldConditions Enable="0" Version="1" />
                </Field>
                <Field index="15">
                    <Name>ДатаН</Name>
                    <SheetColumn>1</SheetColumn>
                    <ValueMode>0</ValueMode>
                    <KeepValue>0</KeepValue>
                    <KeepLevel>0</KeepLevel>
                    <FieldFunctions Enabled="0" Version="1" />
                    <FieldConditions Enable="0" Version="1" />
                </Field>
                <Field index="16">
                    <Name>НомерСчета</Name>
                    <SheetColumn>1</SheetColumn>
                    <ValueMode>0</ValueMode>
                    <KeepValue>0</KeepValue>
                    <KeepLevel>0</KeepLevel>
                    <FieldFunctions Enabled="0" Version="1" />
                    <FieldConditions Enable="0" Version="1" />
                </Field>
                <Field index="17">
                    <Name>ДатаСчета</Name>
                    <SheetColumn>1</SheetColumn>
                    <ValueMode>0</ValueMode>
                    <KeepValue>0</KeepValue>
                    <KeepLevel>0</KeepLevel>
                    <FieldFunctions Enabled="0" Version="1" />
                    <FieldConditions Enable="0" Version="1" />
                </Field>
                <Field index="18">
                    <Name>НамерСФ</Name>
                    <SheetColumn>1</SheetColumn>
                    <ValueMode>0</ValueMode>
                    <KeepValue>0</KeepValue>
                    <KeepLevel>0</KeepLevel>
                    <FieldFunctions Enabled="0" Version="1" />
                    <FieldConditions Enable="0" Version="1" />
                </Field>
                <Field index="19">
                    <Name>ДатаСФ</Name>
                    <SheetColumn>1</SheetColumn>
                    <ValueMode>0</ValueMode>
                    <KeepValue>0</KeepValue>
                    <KeepLevel>0</KeepLevel>
                    <FieldFunctions Enabled="0" Version="1" />
                    <FieldConditions Enable="0" Version="1" />
                </Field>
            </PriceFields>
            <FirstRow>4</FirstRow>
            <LastRowColumn>1</LastRowColumn>
        </SheetConfiguration>
    </Sheets>
</PriceConfiguration>
```

Comment: As with your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58990632/how-do-i-make-program-that-modify-value-percent-in-file-mik-neva-xml), you are adding space characters where they don't belong. `$_.SelectNodes(' //FieldCostOptions/IncreaseCost')` --> `$_.SelectNodes('//FieldCostOptions/IncreaseCost')`

Answer (score 0):

You should capture the xml in a variable in order to be able to manipulate the nodes and/or attributes.
Something like below:

```
$inputFile  = 'D:\MIK_RT.xml'
$outputFile = 'D:\Output.xml'
# read the xml from file into a variable
[xml]$xml = Get-Content $inputFile -Raw

# find and write out the current percentage(s)
$currentPercent = $xml.SelectNodes('//FieldCostOptions/IncreaseCost') | ForEach-Object { $_.GetAttribute("Percent") }
Write-Output $currentPercent

$newPercent = Read-Host -Prompt 'percent'

# update the xml percent attribute(s)
$xml.SelectNodes('//FieldCostOptions/IncreaseCost') | ForEach-Object { $_.SetAttribute("Percent", $newPercent)}
# save the updated xml
$xml.Save($outputFile)
```

---

If you want the file to be saved in UTF-8 encoding, you can do this:

For writing as UTF-8 **with** BOM

```
$sw = [System.IO.StreamWriter]::new($outputFile, $false, [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8)
```

For writing UTF-8 **without** BOM 
(By default, the StreamWriter creates files encoded in UTF-8 without BOM)

```
$sw = [System.IO.StreamWriter]::new($outputFile, $false)
```

Or create an encoding object first:

```
$utf8NoBom = New-Object System.Text.UTF8Encoding($false)
$sw = [System.IO.StreamWriter]::new($outputFile, $false, $utf8NoBom)
```

Now save the file using the StreamWriter object

```
$xml.Save($sw)
$sw.Dispose()
```

Comment: output need to be in utf8 or user cannot read it in local language

Comment: @danrather I have edited my answer and added code for saving in UTF-8